# What is $chk in the following code.I am unable to find it out

Tags: php, javascript

```
function addValueToList(elemlist,elemhidden,elemval,elemlab,elemcheck) {
alert(elemlist);

if ($chk($(elemlist)) && $chk($(elemhidden)) && $chk($(elemval)) && $chk($(elemlab)) && $chk($(elemcheck))) {

    var value = $(elemval).getProperty('value');
    var label = $(elemlab).getProperty('value');
    var check = 0;

    if (value != '') {

        value = value + "||" + label;
        if ($(elemcheck).checked) {
            value = value + ' [default]';
            check = 1;
            cleanOptions(elemlist);
        }

        if (editValue == null) {                
            addOption(elemlist,value,elemval,elemcheck);
        } else {
            if ($chk($(editValue))) {
                $(editValue).setProperty('value',value);
                $(editValue).setText(value);
                editValue = null;
            }
        }

        $(elemval).setProperty('value','');
        $(elemlab).setProperty('value','');
        $(elemcheck).checked = false;

        buildHiddenField(elemlist,elemhidden);

    } else {
        window.alert("Value field cannot be empty !");
    }

} else {
    window.alert("addValueToList : Problem to retreive values ");
}
   }
```

I am calling this function from my coding. but, when the javascript is being called, js error is being caught. "referenceerror, $chk is not defined". I am unable to post total js file. it  is causing problem. What is $chk in this coding? and how to make this error free.... means, have i to define it at top? or how can i get rid of this error?

Comment: it could be a globally defined variable like jquery `$`

Comment: It's a reference to a function. As a developer you need to **LEARN** how to program, because you can see yourself that copy-pasting doesn't make you a better specialist (keeping in mind you cannot understand the trivial code)

Comment: @DevZer0: ... or be defined in an outer scope.

Comment: Old MooTools library function? http://mootools.net/docs/core/Core/Core#Deprecated-Functions

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, it was a MooTools function to check whether the value existed (the value was not null, and was not false or equivalent) and it returned true/false depending on it's given value (Whether it was true or not).

However it has been deprecated now, so if you have updated your MooTools library then it probably won't work anymore as they have decided to not create an alternative.

The only other option is to try:

```
if( ($(elemlist) && $(elemlist).length > 0) && ($(elemhidden) && $(elemhidden).length > 0) && ($(elemval) && $(elemval).length > 0) && ($(elemlab) && $(elemlab).length > 0){
     // Some code here
}
```

Comment: "the value existed" --- what exactly does that mean? (using *real* terms of JS) Does `false` exist? How about `0`?

Comment: "and was not false or equivalent" --- how about `0`?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used MooTools so I don't remember exactly what it did, but I would consider "doesn't exist" to be null, undefined, (and on non-strict checks) false, 0, etc.

Comment: there is a link in the comments to the implementation details

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. DarkMantis. I tried this replacing the existing one, but it is giving "referenceerror:element is not defined"

although element has got some value. it is not blank.

Comment: Try the updated code? I made a mistake ( I was checking for $(element) not $(elemlist))

Answer (score 1):

It is globally defined anywhere in your page.

like `$chk = $;` or `$chk = jQuery;`

you can use `$` or `jQuery` instead of `$chk`

Hope it will help to understand.